# Не работает форма обратной связи

Tags: php, форма

Здравствуйте!
Есть лендинг пока на тестовом домене http://elenadva.beget.tech/
На данный момент там не работает форма обратной связи.
Сообщения не отправляются (при нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит).
Помогите, пожалуйста.
На Опен Сервер работает, на хостинге - нет.
Код формы в index.php:

```html
                   <form role="form" id="contact" action="php/mail.php" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваши ФИО или название организации">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Курс">
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="25" cols="10"
       placeholder="Текст сообщения"></textarea>
                            <input class="btn btn-default submit-btn form_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Записаться на курс"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Код mail.php:

```html
<?php
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
if($post) {
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $error = '';
 if(!$name) {$error .= 'Укажите свое имя. ';}
 if(!$email) {$error .= 'Укажите электронную почту. ';}
 if(!$subject) {$error .= 'Укажите интересующий Вас курс. ';}
 if(!$message || strlen($message) < 1) {$error .= 'Введите сообщение. ';}
 if(!$error) {
  $address = "elena.darek@gmail.com";
  $mes = "Имя: ".$name."\n\nТема: " .$subject."\n\nСообщение: ".$message."\n\n";
  $send = mail ($address,$subject,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:$email");
  if($send) {echo 'OK';}
 }
 else {echo '<div class="err">'.$error.'</div>';}
}
?>
```

Код скрипта js:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $("#contact").submit(function() {
  var str = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "php/mail.php",
   data: str,
   success: function(msg) {
    if(msg == 'OK') {
     result = '<div class="ok">Ваше сообщение отправлено</div>';
     $("#fields").hide();
    }
    else {result = msg;}
    $('#note').html(result);
   }
  });
  return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас у формы нет id, на который у вас js висит. Замените первую строчку формы на это

```
<form role="form" id="contact" action="php/mail.php" method="post">
```

А также замените кнопку на это (смотри ниже). У вас она не submit. А js висит именно на отправку.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit-btn form_submit" value="Записаться на курс">
```

Также к каждому `input` и `textarea` нужно добавить атрибут `name`. Именно с таким именем (которое указано в атрибуте `name`) данные придут на сервер в массиве `$_POST`. Например:

```
<input type="email" name='email' class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
```

Значит в массиве `$_POST` будет запись с ключом `email` из `name` и значением, которое ввели в этот `input`.

код php

```
$errors=array(
    'name' => 'Укажите свое имя.',
    'email' => 'Укажите электронную почту.',
    'subject' => 'Укажите интересующий Вас курс.',
    'message' => 'Введите сообщение.',
);

foreach ($errors as $variable => $error_text) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$variable]) or empty($_POST[$variable])) exit('<div class="err">'.$error_text.'</div>');
}

extract($_POST);

$address = "elena.darek@gmail.com";
$mes = "Имя: ".$name."\n\nТема: " .$subject."\n\nСообщение: ".$message."\n\n";
$send = mail($address, $subject, $mes, "Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:$email");
if($send) echo 'OK';
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67669/discussion-on-answer-by-n-osennij-----).